# Why is Drupal with redis slower than mariadb?

Tags: commerce, caching, database

I've got a big Drupal site running Commerce, with cloudflare caching static resources, maybe 20K users or more per day.

MariaDB caches about 500mb worth of queries, we're running freeBSD with php56 and php fastcgi. I'm using the redis PHP extension.

When I turn on redis for all the cache tables, I see the php-fcgi processes start to spike from 7% CPU up to about 35% and load goes through the roof.

Tried it a couple of times, which would minimize cache stampeding, but still I'm somewhat confused as to why redis is performing so poorly.

I've read through redis.conf and the main change I've made is not to snapshot the db to file.

I can connect with redis-cli monitor and see tons of cache data passing through.

Any ideas about what's happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it got loooads slower recently (the Drupal module). Not sure what they've done but it's not good, sites that took a few seconds to clear cache are now taking 30/40/50 seconds plus. Think I downgraded to earlier than 7.x-2.13 on one site and saw an improvement, try that. The advice in the release notes to use `EVAL` makes no difference as far as I can tell

Comment: Actually I'm clearing the cache on a medium site as we speak, 90 seconds and still going...

Comment: I'm following up in the Redis module issue queue here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2550275

Comment: @Clive FIY I am the module main maintainer, and I'd like to have more information about slowliness you are experiencing. Please open issues in the module issue tracker, I'd very much like to discuss with you about potential improvements. Aside of that, such CPU bump (from 7% to 35%) is nothing like we ever experienced (we use the module on production sites for some time now).

Comment: I will ask a few more questions in the issue you opened in the module issue queue.

Comment: Hi @Pierre, I'll try to follow up with an issue next week (I'm having a few days off at the moment). If it helps at all in the meantime, I've seen a slowdown on multiple sites when clearing caches on different environments (Mac+Homebrew, Ubuntu Server, Pantheon), both through the UI and with Drush, since about 2.13. It's entirely possible something else changed across those environments, I haven't tried that hard to narrow it down if I'm honest, but I can't think of anything other than Redis that was updated around the same time for all sites I noticed it on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic should probably be closed, as the Drupal Redis module maintainer, I am taking over the issue in the module official issue tracker, specific questions are pending there, and a few micro-optimizations have already been done since this question was opened.

For everyone that would help us or need support, please consider participating to https://www.drupal.org/node/2550275 - this would be great help.

Thanks in advance to everyone that will give us a few minutes to solve this and improve the module.